# What could I be doing wrong with my msbuild argument?

Tags: msbuild

I have an msbuild argument

```
/t:Project.HQ.Web /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

in my Azure DevOps Build pipeline for Solution Build.

I get an error that says

> Agent job 1: "Code\AnotherMutliProjSolution.sln(0,0): Error MSB4014:
>   The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
>   System.ArgumentException: The name "Project.HQ.Web" contains an
>   invalid character ".". at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowArgument(Exception
>   innerException, String resourceName, Object[] args) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectTargetElement.set_Name(String
>   value) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectTargetElement.CreateDisconnected(String
>   name, ProjectRootElement containingProject) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectTargetInstance.ToProjectTargetElement(ProjectRootElement
>   rootElement) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.ToProjectRootElement() at
>   Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.CreateSolutionProject(String
>   wrapperProjectToolsVersion, Boolean explicitToolsVersionSpecified) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.Generate() at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.GenerateSolutionWrapper(String
>   projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion,
>   ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext
>   projectBuildEventContext, IReadOnlyCollection`1 targetNames,
>   ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.LoadSolutionForBuild(String
>   projectFile, PropertyDictionary`1 globalPropertiesInstances, String
>   toolsVersion, BuildParameters buildParameters, ILoggingService
>   loggingService, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext, Boolean
>   isExplicitlyLoaded, IReadOnlyCollection`1 targetNames,
>   ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.LoadSolutionIntoConfiguration(BuildRequestConfiguration
>   config, BuildRequest request) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node,
>   BuildRequestBlocker blocker) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueRequestToScheduler(BuildSubmission
>   submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild, BuildRequestBlocker
>   blocker)" Review

I have tried having a my target set as 'Project.HQ.Web' and "Project.HQ.Web". I still run into the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.
What I did was instead of build the solution,
I built the csproj file itself passing in the msbuild argument

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation=$(build.stagingDirectory)\\ProjectHQWeb
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to replace the `.` with underscores to build the generated solution targets:

```
msbuild /t:Project_HQ_Web
```

See the following part of [How to: Build specific targets in solutions by using MSBuild.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2019)

> Specify the target after the -target: switch in the format
>   `<ProjectName>:<TargetName>`. If the project name contains any of the
>   characters %, $, @, ;, ., (, ), or ', replace them with an _ in the
>   specified target name.

Comment: Thank you. I will explore this as an option.

Answer (score 2):

[From the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019), `/t` is used to build target of a project. There is no switch for the project itself.

You must use as command line:

```
msbuild.exe /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" "Project.HQ.Web"
```

Comment: For solutions, MSBuild generates some special targets automatically, like `-t:My_Project_name` or `-t:MySlnFolder\My_Project_Name:Clean`

Comment: (though personally I really don't like to use them)

Comment: Thank you. I will explore this.